# PreferenceScreen size for different device size

Tags: android, android-edittext, preferencescreen

I have a PreferenceScreen but I want have it on big devices also, but the elements don't scale and I cannot change its size. On tablets it looks really small and I want make it bigger, how to do it?

This is how it looks right now:
[image]

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    >

    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="0"
        android:key="longitudeList"
        android:numeric="signed|decimal"
        android:phoneNumber="false"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:summary="@string/longitudeRange"
        android:textSize="100dp"
        android:title="@string/enterLong" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="0"
        android:key="latitudeList"
        android:numeric="signed|decimal"
        android:phoneNumber="false"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:summary="@string/latitudeRange"
        android:title="@string/enterLati" />

    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="10"
        android:entries="@array/refreshArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/refreshValues"
        android:key="refreshList"
        android:title="Select refresh time" />


</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

use sp for text size

```
            android:textSize="20sp"
```

From [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskUseDP)

> When defining text sizes, however, you should instead use
>   scale-independent pixels (sp) as your units (but never use sp for
>   layout sizes). The sp unit is the same size as dp, by default, but it
>   resizes based on the user's preferred text size.
>
> For example, when you specify spacing between two views, use dp:

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/clickme"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

> When specifying text size, always use sp:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: But I want to these edittext fields bigger not text.

Comment: Try, 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content", in each view?

Comment: It doesn't change anything in this case.

Comment: tried changing text size to sp and set the width and height? I mean both are needed